# pgfplots: how to use "index of colormap" to specify a color?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

The MWE below uses the `pgfplots` function `index of colormap` to specify the color of a drawn path. However if I uncomment the second `\draw` command which explicitly uses the `color=` key, I get `` Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `index of colormap={0 of hot}' `` The commented `\shade` command is closer to what I really want to do, namely to use colormap colors in a shade command, where really I have to use the `key=value` syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-2,xmax=2,ymin=-2,ymax=2]
\draw[index of colormap={0 of hot}] (-2,1.5) -- (2,1.5);
%\draw[color={index of colormap={0 of hot}}] (-2,1) -- (2,1);
%\shade[left color={index of colormap={0 of hot}},right color={index of colormap={1 of hot}}] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because `index of colormap` is a sort of style which defines `.` as the resulting color which then calls `color=.`. But when you resort the code a bit it is working. See the code below.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-2,xmax=2,ymin=-2,ymax=2]
        \draw[index of colormap={0 of hot}]         (-2,1.5) -- (2,1.5);
        \draw[index of colormap={0 of hot},color=.] (-2,1.0) -- (2,1.0);
        \shade[
            index of colormap={0 of hot},left color=.,
            index of colormap={1 of hot},right color=.,
        ] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{colormap access=direct} %<-added
\tikzset{mycolor/.code={\pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor{#1}
    }} %<-added
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-2,xmax=2,ymin=-2,ymax=2,colormap/hot]
\draw[index of colormap={0 of hot}] (-2,1.5) -- (2,1.5);
\draw[mycolor=2,color=mapped color] (-2,1) -- (2,1);
\shade[mycolor=0,left color=mapped color,mycolor=1,right color=mapped color] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]